# How to send BTC amount from one specific address in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I canceled one transaction that was in the memory pool, now I would like to make sure that this transaction will not be sent anymore sending all BTC amount of the original address of this transaction to another address, but when I go to send BTC in Bitcoin Core, I can't choose one specific address to send the amount. So what Can I do to "empty" the bitcoins of this address using Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1):

If you run Core with the command line flag `-zapwallettxes` it will forget transactions in its mempool.

Comment: I did that following the steps in this answer:https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it
But in that answer I should also send the bitcoins from this address to another address to make sure this transcation will never be completed.

Comment: New update about that: Even after I cancel the transaction with -zapwallettxes, the transactions was completed, and the other one that I made it is with the status "conflicted". That is strange to me.

Comment: Do blockchain explorers show both as unconfirmed @LucaBlight

Comment: no, I have both TXIDs, but just the txid of the first one is showed in block explorer, the second one does not exist in the block explorer. And now the first one is confirmed.

Comment: If it's confirmed unfortunately it can't be canceled.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no problem about that. I just think that using -zapwalletttxes is not the safest way to cancel one transaction in mempool, it would be better use zapwalletttxes + spend all Bitcoins in that address, but I couldn't find one way through Bitcoin core to select one specific address to spend the Bitcoin in this address.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a new wallet and sending the funds to an address outside of your wallet because you can send them to an address outside of your wallet, right? And then, import the new wallet with the transferred funds.

Comment: Yes I could do that but I think that would be a little bit annoying because I would need to pay 2 fees and I think it should have a way to do that only using the Bitcoin core.